# Is there any way to change the text color in a fragment using kotlin programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

This is sample code, i need to change text color in text view for certain condition. like, for different months text color should different  .
Thank you.

FragmentOne.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup



class FragmentOne : Fragment() {



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)

    }

}
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentOne">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#7654ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="me !" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I am trying to do a calendar app. Each Fragment are months and inside fragments some button or some view for days. now my problem is , how to highlight current date. If possible please help. Thank You and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It depends if you are using some sort of CalendarView or something else or just a simple TextView.

Comment: No calendar view use because, i'm trying to make local language calendar , that means each days no are in local language numbers. So i'm using simple cardview or a textview.

Comment: Have you tried: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextColor(int) ?

Comment: No, I will try. Thank you

Comment: I tryied but i'm confused when it asking me Int value , Before i did not know int value for colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this inside onCreateView method

```
var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
var textView : TextView = view?.findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView
//your condition,then set the color. Use if or when
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED)
```

Comment: I will Try, Thank You !